# VScode `tsx` files formatted to single quotes but `ts` files formatted to double quotes, why that happens?

Tags: eslint, visual-studio-code

I have the following configuration on my VSCode:

```
{
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  },
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  },
  "[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  },
  "[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
  "eslint.validate": [
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact",
    {
      "language": "typescript",
      "autoFix": true
    },
    {
      "language": "typescriptreact",
      "autoFix": true
    }
  ],
}
```

It auto corrects double quotes to single quotes in `.tsx` files, but that inverse happens to `.ts` files, it transforms singles quotes to double quotes.

I'm using ESLint plugin.

Comment: Hey did you get a fix for that problem?